# Hibernate adds unwanted unique key itself In @OneToMany mapping

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, unique-constraint

I have 3 entities in my Spring boot application. `User`,`Item` and `Orders`
I want one `Orders` object to have multiple `Items` so, I used `@OneToMany` mapping in `Orders` class.

This is my code:

This is my `Item.java` file

```
@Entity
public class Item implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="item_id")
private int itemId;
@Column
private String name;
@Column
private int price;
@Column
private String image;
@Column(name = "item_user_id")
private int userId;

//getters ssetters

}
```

This is my `Orders.java` file

```
@Entity
public class Orders implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "order_id")
private int orderId;

@Column(name = "order_user_id")
private int userId;

@Column
@OneToMany
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

//getters setters

}
```

Hibernate is generating 3 tables as I expected
`Item` , `Orders` and `Orders_Item` from above code.

`Orders` table has two columns `order_id` and `order_user_id`

Also
*`Orders_Item` table has two columns `orders_order_id` and `items_item_id`*

**hibernate is making `items_item_id` a unique key, I don't want this**

`Hibernate: alter table orders_items add constraint UK_9uu7j0okufkkanam94v8gb2qa unique (items_item_id)`

**SO MY ISSUE IS I CAN'T INSERT AN ITEM HAVING ONE ID MORE THAN ONCE**

How can this issue be ressolved?

Comment: What do you mean you can't insert an item more than once? Also do you need a birectional or unidirectional relationship?

Comment: Hi @akortex. I want **unidirectional** mapping. By inserting an ```item``` more than once, I mean I have already saved the items in database in the ```item``` table. When I save an ```item``` to ```orders``` table, the ```item_id``` will be saved into the ```orders_items``` table. So the ```unique key constraint``` on ```items_item_id``` is preventing from saving an ```item_id``` more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the unique constraint on `items_item_id` then you have a ManyToMany relationship, you want to associate an item to more than one order. Change your `@OneToMany` annotation to a `@ManyToMany` annotation.

Comment: Also, @ManyToMany relationships are more performant when modeled as a Set instead of a List.

Comment: What if you don't want to a many to many relationship???